# Preview uploaded image in new window using javascript

Tags: javascript, image, file-upload

I have gone through several similar threads/posts, however I am unable to tweak the codes for my requirement. I want the user to upload an image file; this should open a new popup window, where I shall display standard image (with size) and place user submitted image besides it for comparison. I don't want php or ajax to do this; I want to utilize javascript for the same. This is a working code from [Preview Image without Upload to my server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673021/preview-image-without-upload-to-my-server)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function onFileLoad(e) { 
    $('#preview').append('<img src="'+e.target.result +'"/>');  
}

function displayPreview(files) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = onFileLoad;
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="preview"></span>
<input type="file" onchange="displayPreview(this.files);"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I need the preview to open in a new window. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
window.open('e.target.result');
```

Comment: It doesn't work. All I need is the value that I can pass on to the next window; or at least an url to reference the uploaded file.

Comment: I just think when you get image's link e.target.result, you can use window.open(e.target.result) to open it in a new windows
It's work for me.

Comment: What is my file is CSV as I am getting base 64 encoding when I am trying to use `reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);`